# Type of function parameters

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I'm working with basic rock scissors paper game on the codecademy.
I don't understand one step.

```
const getUserChoice = function (userInput) {
console.log(userInput)
userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
if ((userInput === 'paper') || userInput === 'scissors' || userInput === 'rock') {
    return userInput;
} else {
    console.log('Wrong user input')
}
```

}

Why when i put as an argument something else then string it is not working ?

It's working great with getUserChoice('AAA') but it isnt working with getUserChoice (aa).
Could someone explain it to me please?

Comment: `isnt working with getUserChoice (aa)` You're calling `getUserChoice` with a variable `aa`. What does the variable named `aa` contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to run `getUserChoice ('AAA')`, then you are trying to pass `'AAA'` to the function. `'AAA'` is a string (characters starting and ending in single quote), so the function works.

When you try to run `getUserChoice (aa)`, then you are trying to pass `aa` to the function. In this case, `aa` does not begin and end with `'`, so it is not a string. In such a case, JavaScript assumes that `aa` is a variable. Now, if `aa` variable is not defined, then you will get an error.

If you run `var aa = 'some string';` and then run `getUserChoice (aa)`, it won't cause an error.

In a nutshell, your `aa` variable is not defined, that's why you are getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

*It's working great with `getUserChoice('AAA')` but it isnt working with `getUserChoice (aa)`*.
`'AAA'` is a `string` as its wrapped inside `''`. `aa` refers to a variable named `aa`. 
If `aa` is not is not defined it will throw error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: **`aa` is not defined**

If `aa` has a value but its not `string` it will still throw error because you are calling string method `toLowerCase()` in your function.

> "Uncaught TypeError: **`userInput.toLowerCase` is not a `function`"**

To fix this convert `userInput` to `string` before calling `toLowerCase`. Use
[`String()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) to change type.

```js
let aa = 3;
const getUserChoice = function (userInput) {
  userInput = String(userInput).toLowerCase();
  if ((userInput === 'paper') || userInput === 'scissors' ||      userInput === 'rock') {
      console.log("correct");
     return userInput;
  } else {
    console.log('Wrong user input')
  }
}
getUserChoice(aa)
getUserChoice(function(){console.log('sss')})
getUserChoice(55232.3323)
getUserChoice(undefined)
getUserChoice(true)
getUserChoice('paper');
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `aa` is a variable , but if you assign a string to it will work.

Also not the use of `toLowerCase()`. It will work on a string but if you assign a number to `aa` like `let aa = 1`, that will not work. Not here 1 is assigned as a number not string where as `aa='1'` will be a string

```js
let aa = 'AAA'

const getUserChoice = function(userInput) {
  console.log(userInput)
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
  if ((userInput === 'paper') || userInput === 'scissors' || userInput === 'rock') {
    return userInput;
  } else {
    console.log('Wrong user input')
  }
}


getUserChoice(aa)
```